# Why does nginx need glibc?

Tags: nginx

My nginx is build from source statically linking pcre,zlib and openssl.
Versions used :
**nginx-1.16.0**
**openssl-1.1.1c**
**pcre-8.43**
**zlib-1.2.11**

I downloaded the tar balls from the respective websites.

I am trying to start nginx but it fails with the following message:

```
./nginx: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./nginx)
./nginx: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by ./nginx)
```

Installing glibc with the required version as it is not allowed. 
Is it possible to ignore glibc when building nginx ?
Should I bundle pre compiled glibc along with my nginx ?
Why does nginx need glibc?
----------Edit 1 ------
Commands used to compile  :
I compiled this in **RHEL 7.6 which has glbic 2.17**

```
$./configure --with-pcre=pcre_path --with-zlib=zlib_path and --with-openssl=openssl_path --prefix=nginx_root 
$make 
$make install
```

I copied the **nginx_root** into a box which is **RHEL 6.5** and started nginx.
I am looking at the gcc & ld options needed i.e --cc-opt , --ld-opt respectively as per nginx's documentation.
C compilation is not my cup of tea. Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure *everything* (including all dependencies) is statically linked? Also, how did you build it?

Comment: @DanielB I have added the details.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide OS and NGINX information?

This would help to look right tools.

Did you compile it from source of used packet manager?

Comment: I have provided them in the new edits. 
Did you compile it from source of used packet manager? No.
I am trying to compile a static module in RHEL7.6 and trying to use it REHL6.5 as my requirements need it.